# Azure DevOps: In Azure SQL Publish Deployment, Missing values for the following SqlCmd variables:env master

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In Azure SQL Publish Deployment, An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue. Missing values for the following SqlCmd variables:env master. The Azure SQL DACPAC task failed. SqlPackage.exe exited with code 1

1. DevOps Build: SqlProj Build success.
2. DevOps Release: Getting the above mentioned error.

Try 1: Have added the variable master with value master in release pipeline. Not helped.

Try 2:Have added the variable master with value master in build pipeline itself. Not helped too.

[Please see the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/filbp.jpg) image. There is no additional parameter other than server name, username & password]

Comment: What parameters are you providing to the DACPAC task?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/filbp.jpg
[Please see the [1] image. There is no additional parameter other than server name, username & password]

Comment: Your DACPAC requires parameters named "env" and "master". You're not passing the parameters.

Comment: Yes, after passing those variables and values it  worked.